# Bootrap 3 Carousel controls stopped working when switching webhosts

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Ok, so recently we switched from Arvixe, to Squidix for our web host. Everything works just fine on Arvixe, but on Squidix my Bootstrap 3 Carousel stops working as intended. For example, the previous and next indicators do not progress to the previous or next slide. The indicators situated in the middle of the carousel to indicate what slide you are on, no longer work either.

I am using Boostrap 3.3.7 with Jquery 1.12. I tried switching to Jquery 3.2.1 and it has no effect. What am I missing here? Is my code all of a sudden wrong? Is it the host directly? How would a different host effect how jquery and bootstrap work?

Here is my carousel code:

```
   <!-- Slider Section -->
<section id="main-slider" class="no-margin">
    <div class="carousel slide">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="0"></li>
            <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item" style="background-image: url(images/slider/bg1.jpg)">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row slide-margin">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="carousel-content">
                                <h1 class="animation animated-item-1">Full Production Printing Services since 1969!</h1>
                                <h2 class="animation animated-item-2">Sault Printing Company has a wide variety of printing services available for your business today!</h2>  <a class="btn-slide animation animated-item-3" href="services.php">Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 hidden-xs animation animated-item-4">
                            <div class="slider-img">
                                <img src="images/slider/brochures.fw.png" class="img-responsive">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item active" style="background-image: url(images/slider/bg2.jpg)">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row slide-margin">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="carousel-content">
                                <h1 class="animation animated-item-1">Authorized Ricoh Dealer and Service Center</h1>
                                <h2 class="animation animated-item-2">We are the U.P.'s premier Authorized Ricoh Dealer and Service Center. We stand behind our products and know you will too!</h2>  <a class="btn-slide animation animated-item-3" href="equipment.php">Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 hidden-xs animation animated-item-4">
                            <div class="slider-img">
                                <img src="images/slider/img2%20small.fw.png" class="img-responsive">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item" style="background-image: url(images/slider/bg3.jpg)">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row slide-margin">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="carousel-content">
                                <h1 class="animation animated-item-1">Your local Office Supply Dealer</h1>
                                <h2 class="animation animated-item-2">We offer a huge array of office items in store, and if we don't have it in stock, check out our over 1600 page catalog! Free shipping and delivery on every order.</h2>  <a class="btn-slide animation animated-item-3" href="http://www.ecinteractiveplus.com/100401" target="_blank">Order Online</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 hidden-xs animation animated-item-4">
                            <div class="slider-img">
                                <img src="images/slider/img3.fw.png" class="img-responsive">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="prev hidden-xs" href="#main-slider" data-slide="prev"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="next hidden-xs" href="#main-slider" data-slide="next"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </a>
</section>
```

As you can see, I have the main carousel named "main-slider", I have an active element on the middle slide first, and I properly call the data-targets with #main-slider. I have jquery loading in the footer first, then bootstrap.min.js

In my footer, I have:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('.carousel').carousel({
             interval: 6000
         })
    });    
</script>
```

This has worked just fine at timing the transitions for 6 secs. I am at a loss. I don't have any issue running a carousel in bootstrap 4 on this same host for another site with working controls. Why would bootstrap 3 be an issue? Is this a coding issue or a web host issue? If it's a web host issue, what could possibly cause something like this?

Comment: errors in the console?

Comment: there shouldn't be any difference switching host, since bootstrap is a front-end framework, the code is run on viewer's computer instead of server.  with that said do you have any server-side code such as database connection and ajax? you can also try cleaning cache on your server, some host offer caching for faster pageload.

Comment: I had something similar happen to me recently where images and scripts weren't loading - it turned out to be an http/https issue. Have you looked into that?

Comment: im looking into those things now, I didnt think it would be a code issue, but I wasn't sure and wanted to make sure. Im not seeing any errors in the console except one about a resource not loading for font awesome that i have at a cdn link. ill try clearing the cache of the webhost if they let me, and open a ticket with them to see whats possibly going on. Ill leave this up for a few more minutes, if there is no major revelation of a coding issue, Ill remove it. Thanks all!

Comment: @wlin I do have some databases on the backend that connect fine and allow me to manipulate data without an issue, but im not running ajax on anything at this point. Ill look into clearing the web host cache. It is weird because I literally just uploaded the same files I had on the other host and ran into this issue. The only reason I thought it might be a coding issue, is because when I run a local server on my machine, it behaves the same way. No controls or indicators function at all even on local host. But when it was live with this same code, it had no issues.

Comment: I don't know, what I would do is 1) if you have a working copy of the code, try run code comparison 2) upload a clean copy of bootstrap and carousel 3) try use a local copy of bootstrap and any other external lib maybe the CDN is down.. sorry couldn't help you more.